# Setting Font.Size does not work correctly in TFrame constructor with 150% scaling (Delphi 10.2 Tokyo)

Tags: delphi, highdpi

I have a TFrame with 2 Labels. One is set to `Verdana 10` at Design Time. The other is set to `Verdana 10` in the TFrame's constructor.

Design time appearance:

[image]

```
procedure TMyFrame.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetFont;
end;

constructor TMyFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  SetFont;
end;

procedure TMyFrame.SetFont;
begin
  Label1.Font.Name := 'Verdana';
  Label1.Font.Size := 10;
end;
```

I create the Frame dynamically in the Main Form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyFrame := TMyFrame.Create(Self);
  FMyFrame.Parent := Self;
  FMyFrame.Align := alClient;
end;
```

When I run the application, the Label with Font changed at runtime (in TFrame.Create constructor) is disproportionately large:

[image]

If I click on the button, then the label will resize correctly:
[image]

So the code works correctly at runtime, just it does not work in TFrame.Create.

How can this be corrected?

I am running on Windows 10 with 150% scaling, and Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

**EDIT**

Based on comment, I added some handlers for Font.OnChange as below:

```
constructor TMyFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Self.Font.OnChange := FontChanged;
  Self.Label1.Font.OnChange := LabelFontChanged;
  SetFont;
end;

procedure TMyFrame.FontChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // empty
end;

procedure TMyFrame.LabelFontChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // empty
end;
```

What I find very strange is that in this case the result is as expected (i.e. correct `Verdana 10`). Simply setting an OnChange handler for Frame.Font and Label.Font, even if they are empty will get different/correct result.

Any ideas?

Comment: The constructor is too early, before the frame properties are loaded from the stream. Try overriding `Loaded` method and setting the font there instead.

Comment: Thanks. It works in `CreateWnd` method. (no difference in `Loaded`)

Comment: I faced same problem. Happens when the frame's SetParent is called with a scaling parent form as parameter. You can check out exactly when and how this happens by adding an TNotifyEvent handler to TFrame.Font.OnChange and set a breakpoint on it. (Don't forget to call the original handelr assigned to it). - Fixing font scaling issues provides me with apointed head and grey hairs :(

Comment: @H.Hasenack: Yes, please see my added edit - setting a Font.OnChange handler actually causes *different* results.

Comment: This makes sense, this is because there is already an internal Font.OnChange event handler assigned after constructing the frame / label. You need to 'remember' the original event handler that was assigned, and call it from within your own event handler on order to get the original results.